When publishing messages using Redis Stream, is it necessary to aggregate them into chunks?
I am trying to publish messages using Redis Stream. I wonder if I need to aggregate the messages in local like Kafka client and then push them to the broker.
Considering that Redis Stream is based on memory and has a higher writing efficiency than Kafka, can a single message be directly written to Redis Stream? Or is there any benefit in aggregating them into chunks and then writing?

A single message is the only option, so it's fine to do.
Adding messages to a Stream with Redis is accomplished using the XADD command. This command will only allow you to add a single event to the stream.
That said, if you have a lot of events, you could pipeline them.
